# Building Gnuplot from Sublime2 OSX

Tags: sublimetext2, gnuplot, sublimetext

I am struggling to execute gnuplot scripts from Sublime2.

Gnuplot is installed and I can execute it from Terminal (OSX).
My build configuration in Sublime 2 looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gnuplot"]
}
```

when Building it get the following result:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'gnuplot']]
[dir:  /Users/macuser/Documents/Gnuplot]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

How to I set up the build instructions in sublime so the script will be send to gnuplot with the current path as a working directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **Sublime Text 3** on **OS X 10.9**, and I solve the problem with the following procedure:

1. Open terminal and navigate to the Installed Packages on Sublime Text:

   ```
   $ cd ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
   ```
2. Copy the file **Gnuplot.sublime-package** and paste in Desktop.

   ```
   $ cp Gnuplot.sublime-package ~/Desktop
   ```
3. Rename the file to **Gnuplot.zip** and extract the content to a folder, ex. **Gnuplot**.

   ```
   $ cd ~/Desktop
   $ mv Gnuplot.sublime-package Gnuplot.zip
   $ unzip Gnuplot.zip -d Gnuplot
   ```
4. Navigate to the folder, **Gnuplot**, open the file **gnuplot.sublime-build** with any text editor, like vim or, even, sublime text. Don't close the terminal window.

   ```
   $ subl gnuplot.sublime-build
   ```
5. On`terminal` type:

   ```
   $ which gnuplot
   ```
6. Copy the path and with the file **gnuplot.sublime-build** opened previously in step 4, append the following line **path** like this:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["gnuplot", "$file"],
       "path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:",
       "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
       "selector": "source.gnuplot"
   }
   ```
7. Save the file, and open terminal again. Type the following commands:

   ```
   $ cd ~/Desktop/Gnuplot/
   $ zip Gnuplot.sublime-package *
   $ mv Gnuplot.sublime-package  ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages\
   ```
8. Restart sublime text 3, and it will work fine. Sorry with my *bad english*. LOL

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a minimum build system should look something like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/full/path/to/gnuplot"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
}
```

You can also set `"working_dir"` to any specific directory.  Check this page out for further info on constructing a build file:

[Build system reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: I don t know where the the location of gnuplot is on my system. I tried to figure it out by invoking it with the "whereis" command, but I don get any answer. Gnuplot can be invoked with Terminal from any location on my system. Do I need to specify it with sublime? Also: last comma in your answer might be wrong.

Comment: Did you actually install `gnuplot` on your machine? What OS are you using, if linux/OSX try `which gnuplot`.

Comment: Thanks. **WHICH** worked. "/usr/local/bin/gnuplot" OSX 10.8.5

Comment: Cool.  I removed the comma in question, too.